# Matrix A that rotates 2D space by an angle 'a' clockwise

Tags: math, matrix, rotational-matrices

The attached image shows the question and my answer.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me whether it is correct. [image]

Comment: Yeah, that's right. But if you can't check it yourself, you haven't really mastered the material.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) Yeah, it all is very new to me and at uni we go really fast with the material. 4 questions from my coursework are based on this answer, hence it was very important for me to be sure it is correct. :) Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can also find the answer on Wikipedia, see [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Actually to rotate the space clockwise, you need to rotate the vectors counter-clockwise which means your answer is incorrect. You need to switch the sign of *α*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it also depends on whether you regard the vectors as rows or columns. The difference is in the signs on the sines. 
The web sites never seem to discuss this.